# Speedily Read and Parse Data

Tags: c#, parsing, filesize

As of now, I am using this code to open a file and read it into a list and parse that list into a `string[]`:

```
string CP4DataBase =
    "C:\\Program\\Line Balancer\\FUJI DB\\KTS\\KTS - CP4 - Part Data Base.txt";
CP4DataBaseRTB.LoadFile(CP4DataBase, RichTextBoxStreamType.PlainText);
string[] splitCP4DataBaseLines = CP4DataBaseRTB.Text.Split('\n');
List<string> tempCP4List = new List<string>();
string[] line1CP4Components;

foreach (var line in splitCP4DataBaseLines)
                    tempCP4List.Add(line + Environment.NewLine);

string concattedUnitPart = "";
foreach (var line in tempCP4List)
{
    concattedUnitPart = concattedUnitPart + line;
    line1CP4PartLines++;
}
line1CP4Components = new Regex("\"UNIT\",\"PARTS\"", RegexOptions.Multiline)
                    .Split(concattedUnitPart)
                    .Where(c => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(c)).ToArray();
```

I am wondering if there is a quicker way to do this. This is just one of the files I am opening, so this is repeated a minimum of 5 times to open and properly load the lists.

The minimum file size being imported right now is 257 KB. The largest file is 1,803 KB. These files will only get larger as time goes on as they are being used to simulate a database and the user will continually add to them.

So my question is, is there a quicker way to do all of the above code?

### EDIT:

```
***CP4***
"UNIT","PARTS"
"BLOCK","HEADER-"
    "NAME","106536"
    "REVISION","0000"
    "DATE","11/09/03"
    "TIME","11:10:11"
    "PMABAR",""
    "COMMENT",""
    "PTPNAME","R160805"
    "CMPNAME","R160805"
"BLOCK","PRTIDDT-"
    "PMAPP",1
    "PMADC",0
    "ComponentQty",180
"BLOCK","PRTFORM-"
    "PTPSZBX",1.60
    "PTPSZBY",0.80
    "PTPMNH",0.25
    "NeedGlue",0
"BLOCK","TOLEINF-"
    "PTPTLBX",0.50
    "PTPTLBY",0.40
    "PTPTLCL",10
    "PTPTLPX",0.30
    "PTPTLPY",0.30
    "PTPTLPQ",30
"BLOCK","ELDT+"     "PGDELSN","PGDELX","PGDELY","PGDELPP","PGDELQ","PGDELP","PGDELW","PGDELL","PGDELWT","PGDELLT","PGDELCT","PGDELR"
    0,0.000,0.000,0,0,0.000,0.000,0.000,0.000,0.000,0.000,0
"BLOCK","VISION-"
    "PTPVIPL",0
    "PTPVILCA",0
    "PTPVILB",0
    "PTPVICVT",10
    "PENVILIT",0
"BLOCK","ENVDT"
    "ELEMENT","CP43ENVDT-"
        "PENNMI",1.0
        "PENNMA",1.0
        "PENNZN",""
        "PENNZT",1.0
        "PENBLM",12
        "PENCRTS",0
        "PENSPD1",100
        "PTPCRDCT",0
        "PENVICT",1
        "PCCCRFT",1
"BLOCK","CARRING-"
    "PTPCRAPO",0
    "PTPCRPCK",0
    "PTPCRPUX",0.00
    "PTPCRPUY",0.00
    "PTPCRRCV",0
"BLOCK","PACKCLS-"
    "FDRTYPE","Emboss"
    "TAPEWIDTH","8mm"
    "FEEDPITCH",4
    "REELDIAMETER",0
    "TAPEDEPTH",0.0
    "DOADVVACUUM",0
    "CHKBEFOREFEED",0
    "TAPEARMLENGTH",0
    "PPCFDPP",0
    "PPCFDEC",4
    "PPCMNPT",30
"UNIT","PARTS"
"BLOCK","HEADER-"
    "NAME","106653"
    "REVISION","0000"
    "DATE","11/09/03"
    "TIME","11:10:42"
    "PMABAR",""
    "COMMENT",""
    "PTPNAME","0603R"
    "CMPNAME","0603R"
"BLOCK","PRTIDDT-"
    "PMAPP",1
    "PMADC",0
    "ComponentQty",18
"BLOCK","PRTFORM-"
    "PTPSZBX",1.60
    "PTPSZBY",0.80
    "PTPMNH",0.23
    "NeedGlue",0
"BLOCK","TOLEINF-"
    "PTPTLBX",0.50
    "PTPTLBY",0.34
    "PTPTLCL",0
    "PTPTLPX",0.60
    "PTPTLPY",0.40
    "PTPTLPQ",30
"BLOCK","ELDT+"     "PGDELSN","PGDELX","PGDELY","PGDELPP","PGDELQ","PGDELP","PGDELW","PGDELL","PGDELWT","PGDELLT","PGDELCT","PGDELR"
    0,0.000,0.000,0,0,0.000,0.000,0.000,0.000,0.000,0.000,0
"BLOCK","VISION-"
    "PTPVIPL",0
    "PTPVILCA",0
    "PTPVILB",0
    "PTPVICVT",10
    "PENVILIT",0
"BLOCK","ENVDT"
    "ELEMENT","CP43ENVDT-"
        "PENNMI",1.0
        "PENNMA",1.0
        "PENNZN",""
        "PENNZT",1.0
        "PENBLM",12
        "PENCRTS",0
        "PENSPD1",80
        "PTPCRDCT",0
        "PENVICT",1
        "PCCCRFT",1
"BLOCK","CARRING-"
    "PTPCRAPO",0
    "PTPCRPCK",0
    "PTPCRPUX",0.00
    "PTPCRPUY",0.00
    "PTPCRRCV",0
"BLOCK","PACKCLS-"
    "FDRTYPE","Emboss"
    "TAPEWIDTH","8mm"
    "FEEDPITCH",4
    "REELDIAMETER",0
    "TAPEDEPTH",0.0
    "DOADVVACUUM",0
    "CHKBEFOREFEED",0
    "TAPEARMLENGTH",0
    "PPCFDPP",0
    "PPCFDEC",4
    "PPCMNPT",30
```

... the file goes on and on and on.. and will only get larger.

The ***REGEX*** is placing each "UNIT PARTS" and the following code until the NEXT "UNIT PARTS" into a string[].
After this, I am checking each string[] to see if the "NAME" section exists in a different list. If it does exist, I am outputting that "UNIT PARTS" at the end of a textfile.

Comment: Belongs on [codereview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com)?

Comment: @Otiel: Just posted: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/6808/speedily-read-and-parse-data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This bit is a potential performance killer:

```
string concattedUnitPart = "";
foreach (var line in tempCP4List)
{
    concattedUnitPart = concattedUnitPart + line;
    line1CP4PartLines++;
}
```

(See [this article](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/stringbuilder.html) for why.) Use a `StringBuilder` for repeated concatenation:

```
// No need to use tempCP4List at all
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
foreach (var line in splitCP4DataBaseLines)
{
    concattedUnitPart.AppendLine(line);
    line1CP4PartLines++;
}
```

Or even just:

```
string concattedUnitPart = string.Join(Environment.NewLine,
                                       splitCP4DataBaseLines);
```

Now the regex part may well *also* be slow - I'm not sure. It's not obvious what you're trying to achieve, whether you need regular expressions at all, or whether you really need to do the whole thing in one go. Can you definitely not just process it line by line?

Comment: just use something like this to load the file lstStockListRecord = new List<string>(); List<string> lstStrLinesStockRecord = new List<string>(File.ReadAllLines(strExtraLoadFileLoc + strFileName)); then if you need to parse the file use the string.join method along with the split method if you have a constant delim that you are using. you can create a method that passes in the file names and from there use lstStockListRecord = new List<string>();
                    List<string> lstStrLinesStockRecord = new List<string>(File.ReadAllLines(strExtraLoadFileLoc + strFileName));

Comment: Also if you know there's a minimum length (assuming you do based on the question), you could specify an initial capacity for the `StringBuilder`.

Comment: @Jon Skeet: I will post a sample above of what the data being brought in looks like.

Comment: @Jon Skeet: Wow. This increased the speed enourmously. wow. lol. Thanks for that!

Answer (score 1):

You could achieve the same output list 'line1CP4Components' using the following:

```
Regex StripEmptyLines = new Regex(@"^\s*$", RegexOptions.Multiline);
Regex UnitPartsMatch = new Regex(@"(?<=\n)""UNIT"",""PARTS"".*?(?=(?:\n""UNIT"",""PARTS"")|$)", RegexOptions.Singleline);

string CP4DataBase =
"C:\\Program\\Line Balancer\\FUJI DB\\KTS\\KTS - CP4 - Part Data Base.txt";
CP4DataBaseRTB.LoadFile(CP4DataBase, RichTextBoxStreamType.PlainText);

List<string> line1CP4Components = new List<string>(
    UnitPartsMatch.Matches(StripEmptyLines.Replace(CP4DataBaseRTB.Text, ""))
        .OfType<Match>()
        .Select(m => m.Value)
    );

return line1CP4Components.ToArray();
```

You may be able to ignore the use of StripEmptyLines, but your original code is doing this via the `Where(c => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(c))`.  Also your original code is causing the '\r' part of the "\r\n" newline/linefeed pair to be duplicated.  I assumed this was an accident and not intentional?

Also you don't seem to be using the value in 'line1CP4PartLines' so I omitted the creation of the value.  It was seemingly inconsistent with the omission of empty lines later so I guess you're not depending on it.  If you need this value a simple regex can tell you how many new lines are in the string:

```
int linecount = new Regex("^", RegexOptions.Multiline).Matches(CP4DataBaseRTB.Text).Count;
```

Answer (score 0):

// example of what your code will look like

```
 string CP4DataBase = "C:\\Program\\Line Balancer\\FUJI DB\\KTS\\KTS - CP4 - Part Data Base.txt"; 
List<string> Cp4DataList =  new List<string>(File.ReadAllLines(CP4DataBase);
//or create a Dictionary<int,string[]> object

    string strData = string.Empty;//hold the line item data which is read in line by line
    string[] strStockListRecord = null;//string array that holds information from the TFE_Stock.txt file
    Dictionary<int, string[]> dctStockListRecords = null; //dictionary object that will hold the KeyValuePair of text file contents in a DictList
    List<string> lstStockListRecord = null;//Generic list that will store all the lines from the .prnfile being processed
    if (File.Exists(strExtraLoadFileLoc + strFileName))
    {
        try
        {
            lstStockListRecord = new List<string>();
            List<string> lstStrLinesStockRecord = new List<string>(File.ReadAllLines(strExtraLoadFileLoc + strFileName));
            dctStockListRecords = new Dictionary<int, string[]>(lstStrLinesStockRecord.Count());
            int intLineCount = 0;
            foreach (string strLineSplit in lstStrLinesStockRecord)
            {
                lstStockListRecord.Add(strLineSplit);
                dctStockListRecords.Add(intLineCount, lstStockListRecord.ToArray());
                lstStockListRecord.Clear();
                intLineCount++;
            }//foreach (string strlineSplit in lstStrLinesStockRecord)
            lstStrLinesStockRecord.Clear();
            lstStrLinesStockRecord = null;
            lstStockListRecord.Clear();
            lstStockListRecord = null;

//Alter the code to fit what you are doing..
```